# Generic number of Component declaration in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, microprocessor

I want to design a 64 entry register file. Now instead of defining all the registers separately, I want to do it in a more compact form like using a loop.
Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Generate statement is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for generate loop
http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/generate.html